# How to deploy Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial App on Heroku using Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org

I'm new here so I apologize if my post doesn't adhere to standards.

I was doing Mike Hartl's Rails Tutorial where at the end of Chapter 7, my push to heroku doesn't work. Heroku states

> "Application Error An error occurred in the application and your page
>   could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

It works fine locally and I'm not sure what's causing it as it was working fine at the end of Chapter 6. I thought it was something in my gem file but I commented out two gems that were added and it did the same thing.

**Heroku Logs:**

```
2015-04-28T08:16:49.294539+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command        `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2015-04-28T08:16:51.465325+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:179:in `read': No such file or directory - config/puma.rb (Errno::ENOENT)
2015-04-28T08:16:51.465349+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:179:in `_load_from'
2015-04-28T08:16:51.465353+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:40:in `load'
2015-04-28T08:16:51.465355+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:308:in `parse_options'
2015-04-28T08:16:51.465359+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2015-04-28T08:16:51.465357+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:453:in `run'
2015-04-28T08:16:51.465361+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
2015-04-28T08:16:51.465364+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
2015-04-28T08:16:52.165317+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-04-28T08:16:52.205397+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-04-28T08:16:52.206353+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-04-28T08:16:55.767400+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2015-04-28T08:16:58.099736+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:453:in `run'
2015-04-28T08:16:58.099709+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:179:in   `read': No such file or directory - config/puma.rb (Errno::ENOENT)
2015-04-28T08:16:58.099730+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:179:in `_load_from'
2015-04-28T08:16:58.099732+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:40:in `load'
2015-04-28T08:16:58.099737+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2015-04-28T08:16:58.099734+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:308:in `parse_options'
2015-04-28T08:16:58.099739+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
2015-04-28T08:16:58.099743+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
2015-04-28T08:16:58.871301+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-04-28T08:16:58.885119+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-04-28T08:17:43.314547+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by jeryl.barnum@gmail.com
2015-04-28T08:17:47.723769+00:00 heroku[run.3182]: Awaiting client
2015-04-28T08:17:47.792818+00:00 heroku[run.3182]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-04-28T08:17:48.168224+00:00 heroku[run.3182]: State changed from starting to up
2015-04-28T08:17:55.295889+00:00 heroku[run.3182]: State changed from up to complete
2015-04-28T08:17:55.255648+00:00 heroku[run.3182]: Process exited with status 0
2015-04-28T08:17:56.062422+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=friendapp.herokuapp.com request_id=04e23ecb-9945-4e49-a6c7-a8f96bf11a54 fwd="96.41.41.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-28T08:17:57.164362+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=friendapp.herokuapp.com request_id=8e2f6e75-dabe-4377-a449-5f9d8414f49d fwd="96.41.41.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-28T08:17:59.359063+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=friendapp.herokuapp.com request_id=bfc919b3-ed3c-4964-8190-961ca690cdca fwd="96.41.41.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-28T08:17:59.954515+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=friendapp.herokuapp.com request_id=61f2b1d4-570e-47bd-91c1-3189ea8b5565 fwd="96.41.41.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-28T08:18:02.043668+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=friendapp.herokuapp.com request_id=0ca8cede-33b8-42b4-865c-5cdc28596c55 fwd="96.41.41.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-28T08:18:02.583384+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App     crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=friendapp.herokuapp.com request_id=c53a196d-b2f8-4bf9-94fc-acc94c705391 fwd="96.41.41.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

**User Model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
 validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
 VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
 validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 200 },
        format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
        uniqueness: { case_sensitve: false }
 has_secure_password
 validates :password, length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',       '3.2.0.0'
gem 'pg'
gem 'bcrypt',               '3.1.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'puma',           '2.11.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
group :development, :test do
gem 'byebug'
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
gem 'spring'
end
```

Does it look like I'm missing something? I took out my Procfile since I took out the Puma gem but that didn't seem to make a difference. Not sure if I need to include any other files as well...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, looks like you are missing the puma config inside the config/ folder.

```
No such file or directory - config/puma.rb (Errno::ENOENT)
```

**From heroku documentation:**

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#config

Create a configuration file for Puma at config/puma.rb or at a path of your choosing. For a simple Rails application, we recommend the following basic configuration:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```